# Coding a label or text box in access on a report

Tags: ms-access

What I am trying to accomplish: I have a report built that feeds from a button on a form and the info selected on that form. What I need is a code that will allow the report to change the header caption based on the information selected from the print report button on the form. So essentially on my form I have three fields that are drop downs. When I make my selection on the first two fields and I want a report that lists only that information I hit the button that says print report and it works just fine. What I want it to do is when I hit the print report button it will open the report with the a specific title based on what selections were made from the form. So for example on my form I choose the branch from the drop down then I choose an organization from the drop down. When I hit the print report button I want that report to open with the Title of the branch and the organization. I want it to be able to change each time the selections are changed. Essentially update the information from the form to the title or caption of the report. Any suggestions? I found a code I thought would work but I cannot make it work when I tweak the information. I am fairly new to the coding and access world and would appreciate any help. 
Here is the code I was trying to use:I was trying to figure out how to add snipping photos I took but don't know how. Here is the code I was trying to use I solved the problem by passing the new text for the Label.Caption in the "OpenArgs" parameter in the OpenReport command, and used the Open Event for the Report to install the new Caption. It works great!

**Code:**
*>>>    In Control Form Module*

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim aWhere As String
    Dim aStrArg As String

    'Select a WHERE statement (from Global List) based on the Radio Box Group
    aWhere = aDept(Me.Dpt_Chain.Value)
    'Pass a String Argument to the Report to install in the Label
    aStrArg = "TEST 22"
    'Open the Report and pass it a string ...
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Price_1", acViewPreview, , aWhere, acWindowNormal, aStrArg

End Sub
```

*>>>    In Report Code  -  Form opens with "TEST 22" in the Label*

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

  If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
      Me.Controls("Dpt_Label").Caption = Me.OpenArgs
  End If  

End Sub
```

I tried to tweak it to work with mine but can't. this is not my information for my stuff but I thought by tweaking this code I could make my caption/title box on my report change each time different information was selected in my form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: I added a little more info on my original post. I am not sure what more I can add. I took snip it pics of the form and the report but don't know how to add them on here. Not sure that will help much either. I just literally want to code my report header/caption to change each time different info is selected in my form where the print report button is located.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer to [ask]. As it stands, your question is barely even readable due to walls of text and mis-formatted code. Please adjust your post to contain the specific problem, what you are currently doing, and what is going wrong.

Comment: I guess what people are trying to say is that's a big block of hard to read text at the top of your question and people are having trouble getting past it.  Add a double space at the end of a line to force the next line to appear below in a new paragraph.

Comment: What does "can't" mean? Exactly what is the issue - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Your WHERE argument needs explaining. What is aDept() function doing?  Could use a textbox instead of label and eliminate VBA from Open event. Expression in textbox: `=[OpenArgs]`.

Comment: Basically I am new to access by can’t I mean it does nothing when I test it! So essentially nothing happens! Sorry everyone I am new to this site as well as access! I will try to make it more readable tomorrow when I get back to work

Comment: The code I tried to put in earlier that I was using had the OpenArgs but I must be doing something wrong because nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Tested, and this worked for me:

```
Dim strString As String
strString = "Hallllo"
DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewReport, , , , strString


Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.Controls("Label1").Caption = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok I added in the code changing the name to mine from the Halllo of course. But I get an error about the Me.Controls("Label6").Caption = Me.OpenArgs   Am I supposed to be changing something in here for my information? Also with this code since I changed the strString = to my info instead of Halllo will it change each time I select different information from my form or do I need to add this code for each different name in the label?

Comment: Yes this is strange in the degub mode, when I debug it the first time (step by step) I also get an error (the `Me.OpenArgs`is `Null`. But when I close everything and run the code without breakpoint it works every time and the string gets passed.

Comment: Well no matter what I do I get the debug error. I end the debug but everytime I try to run the report the debug window comes back up. It doesn't like the Me.Controls line of this code.

Comment: Maybe you did put a textbox into your report instead of a label?

Comment: Yes it is a text box. I will switch it back to a label. I have tried everything with both. But have not tried this with a label.

Comment: Nope didn't work. I just give up. Me.Controls(Label10).Caption = Me.OpenArgs it does not like that line of code just get the debug error over and over and over

Comment: I would add the attachments of the error but I cant figure out how to add one to my post.